# Dark texture on model, even on solid appears also in texture mode

Tags: shaders

when I go into texture mode I get a pretty weird look of the "body" of the robot, the hat is good though
[image]

things i've tried
remove doubles
change some stuff in shading (I'm bad at this though)
flip over

file: [image]

Comment: can you upload your file? your problem is what? the body is half-dark?

Comment: How should i do that?

Comment: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/help/

Comment: I did so, it doesn't appear on solid anymore but still does on texture  hope you can help me out

Comment: i can't understand . . . please explain better you can and in the easiest way your problem

Comment: It's dark you see, the body and it shouldnt be

Comment: No textures are packed into your file, pack them by going to *File>external data> pack all into .blend* The normals on your hat object are flipped as well, that may help you. Recalculate them with `Ctrl+N` with all selected in *edit mode.* I would also suggest adding more light than a single point lamp to your scene.

Comment: I didn't see [any problem with mesh](http://i.imgur.com/1PoowiW.jpg) except for hat which had normals flipped. Other than that it seems different file was uploaded compared to the screenshot.

Comment: Sorry, I've completely worded myself wrong, i've already fixed the black on solid mode, however, its still in texture mode, how should i fix that, sorry again.

Comment: ive added some light it now look slike this http://i.imgur.com/pueeHJJ.png